# My app shows test ads but no real ads (AdMob Google)

Tags: android, admob

I created an app using Android Studio. Once finished, I added ads and then I published it on Play Store. It did work fine during 10 days, approximately. Google removed my app from the store by misunderstanding (copyrights by I had paid them) so I appealed and they restored it. On the time that the app was not on Play Store (3 days), ads were still displayed on my phone. A couple of days after they restore my app, ads stopped being shown, till now.

I tried everything, ID Units are well written. I created a new ID banner and it is the same. Test ads appear but not real ads.

The logcat is below (filtering with word "gms", the ads library).

PDT: I have the dependences and all stuff needed. Remember that it was working well and suddenly no.

```
12-07 10:18:56.726 22503-22097/? W/ctxmgr: [EventHandler]Dropping runnable, delay=9223370524216439082, runnable=dbe@d4e7bc, workInfo=pkg=com.google.android.gms, lbl=FenceScheduler, start=unspec, stop=unspec
12-07 10:18:56.977 32342-32431/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-07 10:18:59.854 32342-32444/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-07 10:19:01.425 32092-32092/? W/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.al.run(9): Dropping command=send_installed_apps due to Gms not connected
12-07 10:19:36.226 22480-25542/? I/Icing: IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=people serviceId=32
12-07 10:23:24.579 1410-2604/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } U=999: not found
12-07 10:23:24.582 2267-2318/? E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START on com.google.android.gms
```

Comment: Please post the dependencies you added.

Comment: //GOOGLE ADS
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'

//RATE MY APP
compile 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.8'
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev187-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'implementation
"io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

Comment: make sure you have added playstore link on adsmob site.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check your AdMob account first. Your old Ad Unit ID might be revoked and you might need to create a new one.

After that you can check if you have the correct adUnitId (not the test ID) in your XML layout.

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        ads:adSize = "BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-###/###"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. Finally it was problem with AdMob account. If test ID is working, and regular Id no, is problem with account (counting that you are not using TestDevice or ID is written correctly)